# How can I recognize ICMP/ARP packets in pcap.net/SharpPcap?

Tags: c#, network-programming, protocols, sniffer, pcap.net

So this is really strange.
I've tried multiple expressions but I have not yet found a proper boolean expression to recognize if a packet is an ICMP or ARP packet.
I've tried

```
packet.ipv4.icmp != null
```

which resulted in the program entering the block even though the packet is not ICMP
I've also tried

```
packet.ipv4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.InternetControlMessageProtocol
```

but then the program never enters the block even though the packet is ICMP
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we talk about ARP over Ethernet packet vs. ICMP over IPv4 over Ethernet packet:

1) Check if the packet is Ethernet.

```
if (packet.DataLink.Kind == DataLinkKind.Ethernet) {
```

2) Check if the Ethernet packet is ARP or IPv4:

```
if (packet.Ethernet.EtherType == EthernetType.IpV4) {

if (packet.Ethernet.EtherType == EthernetType.Arp) {
```

3) If this is IPv4, check if it is ICMP:

```
if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.InternetControlMessageProtocol) {
```

You might want to check before doing all of the above if the packet is valid.

```
if (packet.IsValid) {
```

Which should guarantee that you won't get null references while evaluating the above.